# Monomial ordering deglex

Tags: abstract-algebra

Show explicitly that the polynomial $x^2yz^2 \in \mathbb Q[x,y,z]$ has more than one remainder modulo set $F=\{x^2y-y^2z,2x^2+yz^2,x^3\}$ with respect to the monomial ordering Deglex with $x>y>z$.

The leading monomials with respect to deglex are $x^2y,yz^2$ and $x^3$.
Should I now just do the division and conclude that there are two remainders $0$ and 
$x^{-1}yz^2$? It just seems to be easy.

Comment: It is, in fact, that easy.

Comment: Is it $x^{-1}yz^2$ a polynomial? No! Then how this could be a remainder on division?

Answer (score 0):

My computation shows that $$X^2YZ^2=X^2f_2-2Xf_3$$ and $$X^2YZ^2=(Z^2-2Z+4)f_1+(YZ-2Y)f_2+4Y^2Z,$$ where $f_1=X^2Y-Y^2Z$, $f_2=YZ^2+2X^2$, and $f_3=X^3$.

In conclusion, there are two different remainders: $0$ and $4Y^2Z$.